# SharePoint 2013 unable to load user profile

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, configuration, mysite

we restored the 2010 user profile DB to 2013,we are getting the issue when we are clicking on  like MySite "AboutMe"

I am getting the error like  "unable to load user profile" I checked the issue I am unable to start the user profile syn service,when I am clicking to start,for some time it was showing starting starting again I was going to stopped stage.

Can you please any one help on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

try adding an account you use for the User Profile Synchronization service to the local admin group. Restart the timer service and click start again.

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried to **Restart the Sharepoint Timer Service** ?
[www.msserveradmin.com/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-synchronization-service-will-not-start](http://www.msserveradmin.com/sharepoint-2013-user-profile-synchronization-service-will-not-start/)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is simple I've been trying to solve that for days just make sure the right service application proxy is mapped so to speak with right web application.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25490.sharepoint-2013-could-not-load-user-profile.aspx